# Trust anchor for certification path not found when using custom client DefaultHttpClient

Tags: android, ssl, self-signed, android-keystore

I am trying to pass my self-signed SSL certificate to my web service. As a test I'm pointing my client to Google.

However I get the following errors:

> Catch exception while startHandshake:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found

then

> return an invalid session with invalid cipher suite of
>   SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL

The full logcat is as follows:

```
08-07 20:05:09.635  25029-25029/com.james.restfultest E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-07 20:05:09.975  25029-25029/com.james.restfultest I/Adreno200-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_RB1.04.01.01.06.043_msm8660_surf_JB_REL_RB1.2_CL2428086_release_AU (CL2428086)
    Build Date: 11/15/12 Thu
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: m/jb_rel_rb1.2
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_RB1.04.01.01.06.043 + e534df6 + 951c251 + 07bf631 + 6aa3ec7 + e04e486 + 9f5646a + 855d11b +  NOTHING
08-07 20:05:10.015  25029-25029/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x54242000 size:2088960 offset:0 fd:61
08-07 20:05:10.015  25029-25029/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x4002a000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:63
08-07 20:05:10.165  25029-25029/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x549c4000 size:2088960 offset:0 fd:66
08-07 20:05:10.165  25029-25029/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x4002c000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:68
08-07 20:05:10.556  25029-25029/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x54cc2000 size:2088960 offset:0 fd:70
08-07 20:05:10.556  25029-25029/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x40033000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:72
08-07 20:05:15.050  25029-25119/com.james.restfultest I/global﹕ call createSocket() return a new socket.
08-07 20:05:15.180  25029-25119/com.james.restfultest W/System.err﹕ Catch exception while startHandshake: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
08-07 20:05:15.180  25029-25119/com.james.restfultest W/System.err﹕ return an invalid session with invalid cipher suite of SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL
08-07 20:05:15.230  25029-25119/com.james.restfultest W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f31390)
08-07 20:05:15.240  25029-25119/com.james.restfultest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
     Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=7; regionLength=-7
            at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:593)
            at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1474)
            at com.james.restfultest.MyAsyncTask.postData(Main.java:197)
            at com.james.restfultest.MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(Main.java:163)
            at com.james.restfultest.MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(Main.java:149)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
08-07 20:05:15.701  25029-25029/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x54242000 size:2088960
08-07 20:05:15.701  25029-25029/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x4002a000 size:4096
08-07 20:05:15.701  25029-25029/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x549c4000 size:2088960
08-07 20:05:15.701  25029-25029/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x4002c000 size:4096
08-07 20:05:15.701  25029-25029/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x54cc2000 size:2088960
08-07 20:05:15.701  25029-25029/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x40033000 size:4096
```

And my code is as follows:
Main activity:

```
package com.james.restfultest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

//Consume Service
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;

//Client SSL



import java.security.KeyStore;

import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;


public class Main extends Activity {

    EditText edtInput;
    Button btnGo;
    TextView txvOutput;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setEventHandlers();

        // check if you are connected or not
        if (isConnected()) {
            edtInput.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
        } else {
            edtInput.setBackgroundColor(0xFF333333);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //new HttpRequestTask().execute();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setEventHandlers() {
        edtInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtInput);
        btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
        txvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txvOutput);

        btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    callRestService(edtInput.getText().toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private void callRestService(String sParam) throws Exception {
        MyAsyncTask myAsync = new MyAsyncTask();
        myAsync.RefreshRefPoints(this, this);
        myAsync.execute("hello", "boys");
    }
}


    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        public Context myContext;
        public Activity myActivity;

        public void RefreshRefPoints(Context ctx, Activity act){
            // Now set context
            this.myContext = ctx;
            this.myActivity = act;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String s=postData(params);
            return s;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            //pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(myContext, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
            //pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        public String postData(String valueIWantToSend[]) {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new MyHttpsClient(myContext);
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://google.com");
            String origresponseText="";
            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1",valueIWantToSend[0]));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2", valueIWantToSend[1]));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
         /* execute */
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity rp = response.getEntity();
                origresponseText=readContent(response);
            }
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
            String responseText = origresponseText.substring(7, origresponseText.length());
            return responseText;
        }

        String readContent(HttpResponse response)
    {
        String text = "";
        InputStream in =null;

        try {
            in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            text = sb.toString();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {

                in.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }

        return text;
    }

}
```

And MyHttpsClient:

```
package com.james.restfultest;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;

import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager;

import android.content.Context;

public class MyHttpsClient extends DefaultHttpClient {

    final Context context;

    public MyHttpsClient(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        // Register for port 443 our SSLSocketFactory with our keystore
        // to the ConnectionManager
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", newSslSocketFactory(), 443));
        return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
    }

    private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
        try {
            // Get an instance of the Bouncy Castle KeyStore format
            KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
            // Get the raw resource, which contains the keystore with
            // your trusted certificates (root and any intermediate certs)
            InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.servercertificate);
            try {
                // Initialize the keystore with the provided trusted certificates
                // Also provide the password of the keystore
                trusted.load(in, "myPassword".toCharArray());
            } finally {
                in.close();
            }
            // Pass the keystore to the SSLSocketFactory. The factory is responsible
            // for the verification of the server certificate.
            SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);
            // Hostname verification from certificate
            // http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d4e506
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            return sf;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

If I instantiate DefaultHttpClient instead of MyHttpsClient then this works and I get the response back, so it is something to do with using SSL, MyHttpsClient or my keystore.

I created the keystore in Portecle simply by creating a new .bks keystore and adding a single certificate called "jamespearce" to it. I can't find an example keystore to test, but I can open this one in Portecle so assume it's ok.

I am completely stumped as to what is wrong here but feel like I'm REALLY close: Can anyone get this to work?

EDIT: Credit to Commonware as he solved this below. It was because Google weren't using my custom certificate and I was not trusting theirs!

Calling my webservice (which definitely uses the same certificate as the client) gets the below log:

```
08-07 22:19:03.722    1951-1951/com.james.restfultest E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-07 22:19:03.963    1951-1951/com.james.restfultest I/Adreno200-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_RB1.04.01.01.06.043_msm8660_surf_JB_REL_RB1.2_CL2428086_release_AU (CL2428086)
    Build Date: 11/15/12 Thu
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: m/jb_rel_rb1.2
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_RB1.04.01.01.06.043 + e534df6 + 951c251 + 07bf631 + 6aa3ec7 + e04e486 + 9f5646a + 855d11b +  NOTHING
08-07 22:19:03.993    1951-1951/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x54242000 size:2088960 offset:0 fd:61
08-07 22:19:03.993    1951-1951/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x4002a000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:63
08-07 22:19:04.133    1951-1951/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x549c4000 size:2088960 offset:0 fd:66
08-07 22:19:04.133    1951-1951/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x4002c000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:68
08-07 22:19:04.553    1951-1951/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x54cc2000 size:2088960 offset:0 fd:70
08-07 22:19:04.553    1951-1951/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x40033000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:72
08-07 22:19:23.982    1951-1951/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x54242000 size:2088960
08-07 22:19:23.982    1951-1951/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x4002a000 size:4096
08-07 22:19:23.982    1951-1951/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x549c4000 size:2088960
08-07 22:19:23.982    1951-1951/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x4002c000 size:4096
08-07 22:19:27.926    2276-2276/com.james.restfultest E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-07 22:19:28.146    2276-2276/com.james.restfultest I/Adreno200-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_RB1.04.01.01.06.043_msm8660_surf_JB_REL_RB1.2_CL2428086_release_AU (CL2428086)
    Build Date: 11/15/12 Thu
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: m/jb_rel_rb1.2
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_RB1.04.01.01.06.043 + e534df6 + 951c251 + 07bf631 + 6aa3ec7 + e04e486 + 9f5646a + 855d11b +  NOTHING
08-07 22:19:28.176    2276-2276/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x54242000 size:2088960 offset:0 fd:61
08-07 22:19:28.186    2276-2276/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x4002a000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:63
08-07 22:19:28.316    2276-2276/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x54ac4000 size:2088960 offset:0 fd:66
08-07 22:19:28.316    2276-2276/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x4002c000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:68
08-07 22:19:28.737    2276-2276/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x54dc2000 size:2088960 offset:0 fd:70
08-07 22:19:28.737    2276-2276/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x40033000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:72
08-07 22:19:33.441    2276-2371/com.james.restfultest I/global﹕ call createSocket() return a new socket.
08-07 22:19:33.581    2276-2371/com.james.restfultest W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f31390)
08-07 22:19:33.601    2276-2371/com.james.restfultest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
     Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <86.168.253.152> != <james pearce>
            at com.james.restfultest.MyAsyncTask.postData(Main.java:186)
            at com.james.restfultest.MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(Main.java:154)
            at com.james.restfultest.MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(Main.java:140)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
     Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <86.168.253.152> != <james pearce>
            at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:185)
            at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.StrictHostnameVerifier.verify(StrictHostnameVerifier.java:61)
            at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:114)
            at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:95)
            at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:381)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:367)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:592)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:510)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:488)
            at com.james.restfultest.MyAsyncTask.postData(Main.java:178)
            at com.james.restfultest.MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(Main.java:154)
            at com.james.restfultest.MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(Main.java:140)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
08-07 22:19:34.082    2276-2276/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x54242000 size:2088960
08-07 22:19:34.082    2276-2276/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x4002a000 size:4096
08-07 22:19:34.092    2276-2276/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x54ac4000 size:2088960
08-07 22:19:34.092    2276-2276/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x4002c000 size:4096
08-07 22:19:34.092    2276-2276/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x54dc2000 size:2088960
08-07 22:19:34.092    2276-2276/com.james.restfultest D/memalloc﹕ ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x40033000 size:4096
```

I'll look into this, but if anyone knows a way around it, please let me know. I know I can trust all certificates with SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER, but what I want to do is trust this certificate from any URL.

Commonware - Thanks again - this was driving me mad ;-)

If you know how to solve this issue then please post as an answer so I can give you credit.

EDIT: OK, it must be time for bed ;-) I just realised SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER is exactly what I need.

Comment: "As a test I'm pointing my client to Google" -- but Google isn't using your self-signed cert. Unless you validate against your self-signed cert *and* the stock set of certificate authorities, the request is sure to fail. Or am I missing something in your explanation?

Comment: Excellent point! It hadn't occurred to me that it wasnow only using my custom trust store.

Comment: FWIW, I have a `TrustManagerBuilder` that helps set up these sorts of chains: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/

Comment: Thank you! I have now another error but I'll post it above.

Comment: `SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL` is a junk value, so ignore it. Its a close to an uninitialized value as Java can get. The cipher suite is only valid if the handshake completes.